# Return empty columns in athena boto response object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-athena

When executing a select query against an athena table via boto3, the response object given is in the syntax:

```
 {
   "UpdateCount":0,
   "ResultSet":{
      "Rows":[
         {
            "Data":[
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"site_name"
               },
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"volume_out_capacity"
               },
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"region"
               },
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"site_ref"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Data":[
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"ASSET 12"
               },
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"10"
               },
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"NORTH"
               },
               {
                  "VarCharValue":"RHW007777000138"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
}
```

Is there an additional argument that can be passed so that the response object will contain columns that do not contain values? Something like:

```
{
                  "VarCharValue":"xyz"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Data":[
               {
                  "VarCharValue":None
               }
```

I have looked through the documentation extensively but cannot find arguments that can describe how to format the response in get_query_results() or start_query_execution()

Comment: Are you saying that you want an extra, empty column in the results? Can I ask why? Did you try just adding another column to your query with a NULL value? (eg `select a, b, c, NULL as xyz from table`)

Comment: No I am not trying to build a column. The columns exist in the source table but they do not contains values and so are not being included in the response syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a option to get that data back directly from Athena.  Alternatively if you use S3 Select instead of Athena, you'll get back a json object with all the columns whether they have data or are empty.

Sample Data:

```
name,number,city,state
coin,1,driggs,
michelle,,chicago,
shaniqua,2,,
marcos,3,stlouis,
```

S3 Select Result:

```
{"name":"coin","number":"1","city":"driggs","state":""}
{"name":"michelle","number":"","city":"chicago","state":""}
{"name":"shaniqua","number":"2","city":"","state":""}
{"name":"marcos","number":"3","city":"stlouis","state":""}
```

Code:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name="<my-profile>")
s3 = session.client('s3')

resp = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket='<my-bucket>',
    Key='<my-file>',
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression="SELECT * FROM s3object",
    InputSerialization={'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use", "RecordDelimiter": '\r\n'}, 'CompressionType': 'NONE'},
    OutputSerialization={'JSON': {}},
)

for event in resp['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
    elif 'Stats' in event:
        statsDetails = event['Stats']['Details']
        print("Stats details bytesScanned: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesScanned'])
        print("Stats details bytesProcessed: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesProcessed'])
        print("Stats details bytesReturned: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesReturned'])
```